# How to use traditional sessions in Feathers js

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, feathersjs

Feathers auth provides only JWT authentication, even if strategy is local.
Should I make full custom middleware for `express-session` usage and clean `passport` implimentation just to achive regular sessions behaviour or there's some solutions for this purpose?

Also, I want to use `passport.socketio` for autheticate sockets aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Using Feathers authentication module is entirely optional and you can always register your own middleware at any point like [before and after a service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware). This means you can set up a normal Express session setup and then set [req.feathers](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#params) to the information from the session that you also want to pass to Feathers services (like the user). As you mentioned, you will have to do the same thing with websockets (which also allow setting `handshake.feathers` in its middleware).

A full tutorial how to set up sessions and using authentication can be found in the [Using A View engine](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/express/view-engine.html) cookbook documentation.

Comment: Dead link, consider revisiting